# How to center one div and have another div float to the right of it?

Tags: css

Tried searching for this and I couldn't find an answer.

I have a container set at `728px` with two divs inside of it, and both divs are set to `width: auto;`. I would like to center one of those divs, and have the other float on the right [like in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mk4F.jpg).

The closest I've gotten is using `text-align: center;` for the main container, `display: inline-block;` for the center div, and `float: right` for the right div, but I ended up with [this result instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKquZ.jpg).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make the floating one absolutely positioned and tweak its position accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this works for static content nicely. Do you know if this would work for dynamic content?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe you could use percentages to denote margins/position?

Comment: Hmm, that might work. I'll go ahead and report back once I get it working.